# datatable search not filter well

Tags: angular, datatable

i'm using angular with backend node.js

when i use put text or number in searching ... data not filter what i want

example: when i filter id and put number = 4 it should be remove all rows without row number = 4

i didn't get this

HTML:

```
  <table id="example"   class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="bg-dark text-center">
    <tr class="text-white">
      <th>id</th>
      <th>full name</th>
      <th>gender</th>
      <th>phone</th>
      <th>action</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-center" *ngFor="let s of get_customer">
    <tr>
      <td>{{s.id}}</td>
      <td>{{s.full_name}}</td>
      <td>{{s.gender}}</td>
      <td>{{s.phone}}</td>
      <td class="d-flex">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success mr-2 " href="customer/{{s.id}}">go</a>
        <button class="btn btn-sm mr-2 btn-warning" (click)="setActiveTutorial(s.id)" type="submit">show order</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

TS:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable(
              {
              "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.22/i18n/Arabic.json"
              },
    
            });
          });
        }, 500);


     
        this.customerService.Allcustomer().subscribe(data => {
          this.get_customer = data
        })
     }
```

what should i do ?

Comment: It’s not a good idea to mix jQuery with Angular.

Comment: Use angular material data table instead of jquery.